# Emacs change list auto indenting

Tags: list, emacs, tabs, auto-indent, major-mode

I love Emacs' auto indentation, however I have one issue with it (in every major mode I've tried) and that is auto indenting lists.

This is how all major modes I've used so far indent lists:

pseudo code:

```
variableFoo = [
               valueOne,
               valueTwo,
               valueThree
              ]
```

However, this is what I actually want:

```
variableFoo = [
    valueOne,
    valueTwo,
    valueThree
]
```

So instead of having the values 1 space farther than the opening bracket, I want them to be 4 spaces farther than the variable definition. Or it can be seen as since it's 1 level deeper (in a list) and should have 1 indentation of 4 spaces. Lastly the closing bracket should be on the same column as the variable definition.

I would assume that the indentation is defined inside the major mode (be it Ruby, Haskell, Erlang, C, etc) But maybe there's a way to adjust the auto indentation that it would work this way by default?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

So I've found the solution for Ruby which is simply adding:

```
(setq ruby-deep-indent-paren nil)
```

To your emacs file. However this only works for Ruby and doesn't solve the problem for Haskell / Erlang / Elixir

Comment: FWIW, the indentation you say you want is the one I always set up as default in all the indentation modes I wrote.  I'd consider the other (deeper) indentation as a misfeature (but you should be able to get it when you want it by not putting a newline right after the open paren/bracket).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I decided to just write a general purpose tab mode and I have to say I'm surprised how well it's working out. I never write lisp so this was a fun sunday project. If no one posts a solution for this by the time I'm done I'll just post my mode as an answer if I think it's good enough.